# Changing folder structure in Angular 4

Tags: angular

i am very new to angular development and i dont know if this is very relevant to ask as a question. my problem is this. i have a service named `ServiceUserService` inside a folder called services. i am using this services in several components (like 15).

```
import { ServiceUserService } from '../../../services/app.service-user'
```

so what if i want to put this `ServiceUserService` to a different folder. now do i have to manually change all the paths where i have imported them. since there are only in few components i have imported that, it is doable. but what if there are more ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you change the location of your service you will need to update all of the components for example using that service. When you try and compile your TypeScript you should encounter errors if you have missed anywhere.

If this affects multiple services, going forward I would reccomend creating an `index.ts` file in your `services` folder like the following:

```
export * from "./app.service-user";
export * from "./other.service-etc";
```

You can then change your imports to:

```
import { ServiceUserService, OtherServiceEtc } from '../../../services'
```

That would help slightly with moving around services.

Comment: I have seen in some places that it can be imported like this `import { MyDatePicker } from 'mydatepicker';`. how does this work

Comment: @pavithrarox That is a completly different question that I do not have the answer to!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but if I remember correctly, you can create aliases in order to simplify imports. Add following to `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "baseUrl":"src",
  "paths":{
    "@app/*":["app/*"],
    "@env/*":["environments/*"]
  }
}
```